# Where object should be validated?

Tags: php, validation

My problem is that I don't know, witch solution for the validation of input is better and if there is another, better solution. Well, where object should be validated? On the one hand, the object should always be correct. On the other hand, if the user specifies several incorrect data, it's a more elegant solution to notify him of all errors, not just one (first occured).

```
// Solution 1:
try {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFirstname($_POST['firstname']);
    $user->setSecondname($_POST['secondname']);
    $user->setLastname($_POST['lastname']);
    $user->hasLeftHand($_POST['has-left-hand']);
    $user->hasRightHand($_POST['has-right-hand']);
    $user->setHandedness($_POST['handedness']);
    $user->save($pdo);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Solution 2:
$user = new User();
$user->setFirstname($_POST['firstname']);
$user->setSecondname($_POST['secondname']);
$user->setLastname($_POST['lastname']);
$user->hasLeftHand($_POST['has-left-hand']);
$user->hasRightHand($_POST['has-right-hand']);
$user->setHandedness($_POST['handedness']);

$errors = $user->validate();
if (empty($errors)) {
    $user->save($pdo);
} else {
    echo 'Some errors occured: ' . implode(', ', $errors);
}

// Solution 3:
try {
    $user = new User();
    $user->setFirstname($_POST['firstname']);
    $user->setSecondname($_POST['secondname']);
    $user->setLastname($_POST['lastname']);
    $user->hasLeftHand($_POST['has-left-hand']);
    $user->hasRightHand($_POST['has-right-hand']);
    $user->setHandedness($_POST['handedness']);
    $user->save($pdo);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors = $user->validate();
    echo 'Some errors occured: ' . implode(', ', $errors);
}
```

In **solution 1** each *set* method validates the input. Therefore, the object is always correct. The *save* method only saves the object in the database. On the other hand, if all the data is incorrect, it will be displayed only the first error.

In **solution 2** we allow that object can not be correct between *set* calls, but to the database can be saved only valid object. *set* methods do not validate the input. *validate* method validates the object as a whole, and returns a list of all errors found. *save* method looks like this:

```
public function save(PDO $pdo)
{
    if(! empty($this->validate())) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid state');
    }

    // Store in database
}
```

In this solution is easier to validate the object. Becouse, how should work code below in **solution 1**?

```
$user->hasLeftHand(true);
$user->hasRightHand(false);
$user->setHandedness('right');
```

Or this code:

```
$user->setHandedness('right');
$user->hasLeftHand(true);
$user->hasRightHand(false);
```

**Solution 3** is a copy of **solution 2**. Code of *User* class is the same. Changes only its use - try-catch block. In my opinion, this code looks more clearly.

Comment: I'd say your User object is doing too much. In my opinion it should only hold the data and let the population, persistence and validation been handled by other classes.

Comment: I understand, but what You mean by "population, persistence"?

Comment: With persistence I mean I would have a separate class thats handling how and where the User object is being saved, the User object itself only holds data. With population I mean the setting of the data into you User object, you could have a class that is responsible of setting the data into your User object, this class could then also use a Validator to validate the data before setting it (like in the Symfony Forms NDM linked to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation of input should be separated from validating the correctness of a domain object itself. Many frameworks use Form classes for this. Maybe have a look at how it's done in:

- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html) (Form InputFilters)

In short, the form will validate the input, and will populate a bound object in case the data is valid.

disclaimer: this question is opinion based, and there is no 1 correct answer... but I'll true to recap what we discussed in comments and how I think most people solve it.

**separate input validation from the model**

```
<?php

// class for input validation
class UserValidator
{
    public function validate(array $data)
    {
        $errors = array();
        if (isset($data['email'])) {
            if (!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors['email'] = 'email not valid';
            }
        } else {
            $errors['email'] = 'email is required';
        }
    }
}

// model class itself, does not implement extensive validation
class User
{
    protected $email;

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        // only make sure we have a valid string, dont validate email again
        if (!is_string($email) || !strlen($email)) throw new \InvalidArgumentException('invalid email given');

        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

So this example separates the input validation so it is easy to provide user feedback when processing form data. The model itself only performs basic checks, and assumes the developer is smart enough to set sane data...

```
<?php

// where you process a form POST...
$validator = new UserValidator();
$errors = $validator->validate($_POST);
if (count($errors)) {
    // provide feedback to your user, he gave us bogus data...
    return $errors;
}

// if we are here, we passed validation and can assume our data is good
$user = new User();
$user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
```

This is a **very** simplified example, again you should check out how the major frameworks solve this problem, they've had many people thinking hard about this already...
And as the differences between Zend and Symfony underline: there is no golden hammer for this.

Comment: Are you suggesting I should create a class *UserValidator*, which processes the *$_POST* array and returns *User* object?

Comment: That could be one way to separate the validation from the domain object, yes. But validation libraries are widely available, I wouldn't recommend building your own.

Comment: But this solution also has disadvantage becouse *User* object still has *set* methods. If I call *$user->hasLeftHand(true);* object must check if user has left hand.

Comment: But that is domain business logic error, your form should not allow you to enter invalid data, hence the form should check if all data is correct, before calling the actual object's setters (who also only allow valid data to be set!).

Comment: And here we return to the point of entry. Where should be the validation of business logic? In *set* methods or in *validate*. Errors of logic should be displayed to the user if there are a few at a time, all should be displayed. Like for this example:

`$user->setHandedness('both');
$user->hasLeftHand(false);
$user->hasRightHand(false);`

Comment: There can only be one businesslogic error, if a businesslogic error occurs, it should be handled. This is where it differs from input validation imo. Think of it this way: your domain object can at no time be in an invalid state.

Comment: OK. I wonder still about one. Some *UserValidator* class creates an *User* object. This object has a method *setEmail*. It is known that *UserValidator* check if the email is correct and then call this method, but the method setEmail also should make sure it is correct email. It turns out that the *User* object should check the same what *UserValidator* and additionally business logic.

Comment: As I said, this question is opinion based, it's up to you if you want to duplicate the check, in effect the validator check would be an input validation used to provide user feedback, the second check would be the businesslogic check that makes sure the model is valid, throwing an exception if its invalid.

Comment: I've added a recap of my thoughts in my answer, I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I agree that this question is a lot of answers. But I wanted to just find out what the solution is the most optimal and/or most frequently used. I think your answer pleases me.

Comment: Just seems to me that *UserValidator* should return an object of type *User*. It is more difficult to create object with invalid data. Simply, object from input data we create throught the validator, and if somewhere in the code it is created directly, we should have given specific attention to whether the data are surely correct. But on the other hand, it is strange to create any object by another object - validator.